# Query mongodb for an array of all subdocuments in a collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I can't seem to find a solution for this. I have a collection of users, each user has a subdocument array of payments. I want to be able to load all the payments of all users and add them to a table.

my schema looks like:

```
Users: 
 {name: String,
 surname: String,
 payments: [
   {date: Date,
   amount: Number}
]}
```

I have run the following query in the node console and it returns a list of documents:

```
var allPayments = Users.find( { "payments.amount": { $exists: true }} );
```

, but when I add it to my route and console log it, I get a Query{} document with my schema not the list of documents. I have tried adding `.lean() and .pretty()` but they return errors saying they are not functions, same as when I try to run a forEach() (maybe im doing it wrong).

I have also tried using aggregate as below:

```
var test = Users.aggregate([{$unwind: '$payments'},{$sort: {'payments.date': 1}},{$group: {_id: 0, 'payments': {$push: '$payments'}}}])
```

and what I get back is:

```
Aggregate {
  _pipeline:
   [ { '$unwind': '$payments' },
     { '$sort': [Object] },
     { '$group': [Object] } ],
  _model: Model { Users },
  options: {} }
```

this is my route

```
router.get('/payments', function(req, res) {

    var allPayments = Users.find({
        "payments.bank": {
            $exists: true
        }
    });

    var test = Users.aggregate([{
        $unwind: '$payments'
    }, {
        $sort: {
            'payments.requestdate': 1
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: 0,
            'payments': {
                $push: '$payments'
            }
        }
    }])

    console.log(test)
    console.log(allPayments)

});
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using Mongoose btw?

Comment: Hi, I am using mongoose, it's how I built my schema, in the model I was just showing the structure not the entire code, unless I'm missing something @Besto

Comment: Sorry, since you didn't add it as a tag, I just assumed you were using some other similar library that was behaving strangely. You should maybe know that all Mongoose queries are promises, so you'd need to `await` in order to process the array.

Comment: I recommend you use Typescript so that it will tell you these errors in lieu of spending hours debugging a type error. You would have known this seconds after writing it.

Comment: @EmilC.Try using an aggregation with a `$group` stage (this is grouping of all users) and then `$push` the `payments` sub-document in to an array - I think that gives you an array of the payments of all users.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the issue by changing my schemas, I basically made payment I to its own schema and then included the user ID into each payment that is created. Then I just ran a db. Collection. Find() to load all payments